# Auto open several Userforms

Tags: excel, userform

I am creating a template in excel for a project that contains several UserForms.

How can I set a rule to auto open a specific Userform, based on values entered by users?

Comment: You just need a worksheet_change event

Comment: Or [Workbook.SheetChange Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-sheetchange-event-excel). Be sure to write the code on ThisWorkbook and for the `Worksheet_Change` on the desired Sheet.